# android sqliteDatabase table creation with unique key constraints not throwing exception for duplicate entry

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, constraints

i have created one android application that was connecting to sqlite database.

and i have given a `unique constraint` for multiple fields exactly 2 fields say `username and password.`

am expecting the app will thrown exception while am trying to insert the duplicate entry.

and in the Logcat am getting the following exception :

`01-04 16:52:06.604: E/SQLiteDatabase(1432): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed`

in the line am trying to insert `db.insert(userTable, null, cv);`

but even if am writing this code in a `try..catch` block the control is not entered into my `catch` block.
Experts please tell why this case happends.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and post your try/catch section please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use as below:

```
try{
    db.insertOrThrow(userTable, null, cv);
}
catch(SQLiteConstraintException ex){
//what ever you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try catching SQLException instead of SQLiteConstraintException

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
try{
     db.insertOrThrow(userTable, null, cv);
} catch (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException ex) {

}
```